# Dark Energy EoS: which models ruled out, which remain?

Tags: cosmology, dark-energy

Dark energy density is mostly assumed to be a constant, where the equation of state for w=-1 (for radiation it would be w=1/3, for matter w=0 and for curvature -1/3), so in the simplest model the scalefactor-dependent DE-density parameter

$$\Omega\Lambda(t)=\Omega\Lambda\cdot a^{-3(w+1)}=\Omega\Lambda\cdot a^{0}=\text{constant}$$

But there are also other models with a dynamical equation of state, most famously for example the Jassal-Bagla-Padmanabhan parametrization, where

$$\Omega\Lambda(t)=\Omega \Lambda \cdot a^{-3\cdot (w_0+1)} \cdot e^{\frac{3\cdot (a-1)^2 \cdot w_1}{4\cdot (a-1)\cdot a+2}}$$

and a whole bunch of other Quintessence and Phantom Dark Energy models like the Upadhye-Ishak-Steinhardt, the Hannestad-Mörtsell, the Barbosa-Alcaniz or the Feng-Shen-Li-Li parametrization and so on and so forth, just to name a few (out of a few dozen).

The question is: which models are already ruled out, and which ones are still in the race? I found some old articles using outdated WMAP constraints here, but I heard things have changed with Planck 2013, where it is said that a whole lot of parametrizations were ruled out, but some remained.

Does anyone have some up to date information which models to trash, and which to keep?

Clearing out the dung,

[image: signature]

Comment: [This seems a pretty good summary of the post-Planck situation](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6161)